# Laravel named routes won't work on wampserver

Tags: laravel, routes, wampserver

after activating rewrite_module in the wampserver2.5 console under Apache->Apache modules->rewrite_module, "normal" routing worked just fine. 
However if I use named routes it doesn't

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('post/listing', array('uses'=>'PostController@listing','as'=>post.listing));
Route::get('post/single', array('uses'=>'PostController@single','as'=>post.single));    
?>
```

--  ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)
Use of undefined constant post - assumed 'post'

```
<?php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('post/listing','PostController@listing');
Route::get('post/single', 'PostController@single');
?>
```

Above code works . Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('post/listing', array('uses'=>'PostController@listing','as'=>'post.listing'));
Route::get('post/single', array('uses'=>'PostController@single','as'=>'post.single'));
```

notice the `'` around route names.